# Symfony2 form group validation

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I try to use group validation in my form like that:

In the type class:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(

        'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            //if ($data->type == 0) {
            //    return array('Facebook');
            //} else {
            //    return array('mobile');
            //}
            return array('Facebook');
        },
    ));
}
```

And in my entity:

```
class Challenge
{
  /*
  * @Type("integer") 
  */
  public $id;

  /*
  * @Type("string") 
  * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"Facebook"})
  */
  public $title;
}
```

The problem is that validation for the title field is not triggered.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: have you enabled annotations validation in your config file? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#configuration

Comment: Yes the annotations validation is activated

Comment: Does the validation work if you change it to this: `'validation_groups' => array('Facebook'),` or doesn't that work either?

Comment: Ok I have found the problem it was "/*" instead of "/**"..

Thank you :)